# Gather data from HTML form with dynamically generated fields (list)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, coldfusion

I have a form where I generate a field on button click (fields are identical).

Until now I tried just using unique names for each field but then I can't loop through them because I don't know how many fields I have!

Can I use:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <select name="personid">
         <options>...</options>
      </select>
      <select name="personid">
         <options>...</options>
      </select>
   </li> 
   <li>
      <select name="personid">
         <options>...</options>
      </select>
      <select name="personid">
         <options>...</options>
      </select>
   </li>
   ... 
</ul>
```

And then after I post the form loop through the list somehow and access all fields?

Any ideas on how to access the data after I post?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking, I'm afraid. The fact all of the fields have unique names doesn't stop you from iterating through them at all, `$('ul li select').each(fn)`

Comment: Sorry about that (super junior web dev here). I understand that I can loop through the items from a script in that page but how can i do that after I've posted the form? How can I structure the list in the form so that it can be iterated after posting? Thanks @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: In ColdFusion (which you've tagged your question as so guess that's what you have server side), then CF will covert all the `personid` values into a list of values. You can then access them as `form.personid` and loop over the list.

Comment: Post your form to a page that has this code, and nothing else.  `<cfdump var="#form#">`.  Read everything that is there.

Comment: You're right @JohnWhish CF does indeed concatenate all values of personid into a string, values are separated by a comma. It shouldn't be too hard to split it up and loop over it! Thanks

Comment: _It shouldn't be too hard to split it up and loop over it_ - Unless values explicitly have a comma.

Comment: They don't indeed. Although I'm unsure how to pass the coldfusion variables into a javascript function to do the job. Coldfusion is so handy but man it makes things hard when dealing with javascript.

Comment: What does this have to do with javascript? CF has nothing do with how your code chooses to arrange the html elements. It simply returns generated html.  It would help if you explained [what you are actually trying to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/174378), instead of *how* you are trying to do it ;-) It is possible a different approach would work better, but it is hard to recommend anything without knowing the ultimate goal.

Answer (score -1):

On your action page, all of the values for the same field name will be separated by commas. You can loop through them as a simple list. Just make sure your  values don't contain commas!